# ThinkingSphinx: When using search_for_ids how to get the associated sphinx weights?

Tags: thinking-sphinx

Is it possible when using `search_for_ids` to also get the associated sphinx weights?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by [Pat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/54500/pat) on [github](https://github.com/pat/thinking-sphinx/issues/1037#issuecomment-269889081):

> It is indeed possible, albeit a little less elegant than usual:
>
> `ThinkingSphinx.search_for_ids('ruby', :select => '*, weight()').raw`
>
> This will return an array of hashes with Sphinx's raw results.